# Using round() function to round values in a Pandas Dataframe (df)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to check how may we use the simple basic round() function to round values in a pandas dataframe to a specific number of decimal points. I kept playing around but I couldn't get it right and I am very new to Python so am not looking for anything too sophisticated.

I understand if you use round(3.986, 2) it will simply output to 2 d.p. as 3.99.

And I know we may access the df values through df.values.

I tried exploring the df.applymap() function too.

Help !

Comment: I think you have the right understanding of `round`. What is it that you exactly want to know?

Comment: I would like to know how may we use the round() function to round the values in any given dataframe (df). I know I can access the values via df.values but I can't do round(df.values, 3).

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html?](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` on the column which you want to round the numbers

```
>>> df['Numeric Column'].apply(lambda x : math.round(x,2))
```

This will give you the intended result